# Two classes have the same name in HTML and BeautifulSoup is only selecting the first class

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

The linked page below has two classes of the same name with data in them.  I'm trying to mine the player names from these and assign positions of where they placed in the tournament.  The find function in beautifulsoup is only allowing me to grab the first instance of the class.

I've tried a few different iterations of trying to iterate past the first instance of the class but nothing has worked.  Having two instances of Table2__tbody seems to be the problem, how do I get past the first one and mine the data from the second one.

```
    url_page = "https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard/_/tournamentId/401056502"
    page = requests.get(url_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    name_list = soup.find(class_='Table2__tbody')

    name_list_items = name_list.find_all('a')
```

name_list is only capturing the data from the first instance of Table2__tbody.  What I need is only the data from the second instance.

Comment: You already seem to know about `find_all`; why don't you use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are not quite getting into the right attribute. The 'Table2__tbody' was only pointing to the first table of the hole_playoff results. The attribute you are looking for is actually 'tl Table2__td'.

So when you run the following code (run in python3) and BS4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

url_page = "https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard/_/tournamentId/401056502"
page = request.urlopen(url_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

name_list = soup.find_all(class_='tl Table2__td')
name_list_items = []
for i in name_list:
    name_list_items.append(i.get_text())
```

you actually get a list with the position of the player on the even indexes, and the name on the odd indexes. Some simple data manipulation can arrange that to do whatever you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

One solution how to select the proper table is using CSS selectors.

`table:has(a.leaderboard_player_name)` will select `<table>` that contains `<a>` with class `leaderboard_player_name`, which is our player list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_page = "https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard/_/tournamentId/401056502"
page = requests.get(url_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

table_with_namelist = soup.select_one('table:has(a.leaderboard_player_name)')

for a in table_with_namelist.select('.leaderboard_player_name'):
    print(a.text)
```

Prints:

```
Xander Schauffele
Tony Finau
Justin Rose
Andrew Putnam
Kiradech Aphibarnrat
Keegan Bradley

...etc.
```